# For the last block to hide the button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a test page

For the last block to hide the button

My code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg6auu7c/)

```js
    $("#test_inner .test-item").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".next-btn").click(function(){
        if ($("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().length != 0)
            $("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $("#test_inner .test-item:visible").hide();
            $("#test_inner .test-item:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_inner">     
    <div class="test-item">DIV1</div>
    <div class="test-item">DIV2</div>
    <div class="test-item">DIV3</div>
    <div class="test-item">DIV4</div>
    <div class="test-item">DIV5</div>
    
    <a href="#" class="next-btn">send</a>
</div>
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What block do you want to hide? DIV5??

Comment: @ Yandy_Viera yes for div5 - hide btn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a counter and keep a check on last element. If last element is reached hide the button.

Here is the updated code:

```
var i = 0;
$(".next-btn").click(function(){
    i++;
    if(i == 4)
    {
           $(this).hide();
    }
    if ($("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().length != 0)
        $("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $("#test_inner .test-item:visible").hide();
        $("#test_inner .test-item:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
    if ($("#test_inner .test-item:visible").length == 0)
        $(".next-btn").hide();
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg6auu7c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/jose_mar/rg6auu7c/3/)

```
$("#test_inner .test-item").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

var array = $(".test-item");
var index = 0;
$(".next-btn").click(function(){
if(index==array.length-1){
    $(this).hide();
}

array.eq(index++).hide();
array.eq(index).show();
```

})